# Android display confusion for loops

Tags: android, xml

I am making an app on an android and in one of my views, I want there to be a row filled with items and right below that row, would be comments.

Here is my parent for the row table.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.phaseiii.WorstRestaurant">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and here is the code for the rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tr_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameHeader"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addressHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operatorNameHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operatorEmailHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/complaintsHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionHeader"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp";



</TableRow>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how i would implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is only "row filled with items and right below that row, would be comments", you can use only one `RelativeLayout` to achieve.

I suggest you use those properties:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft
android:layout_alignParentRight
android:layout_below
android:layout_toRightOf
```

Hope this help!